# Python requests: how to make http only request?

Tags: python, get, python-requests, python-3.6

When I try to make a request using `http://` some websites perform a redirection and I find the final destination starting with `https://`.

How can I make my request only support `http://` and not accept `https://`?

For example, this code:

```
import requests
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings() # to disable warnings

response = requests.get("http://facebook.com",verify=False,timeout=5)
responseURL = response.url 
print(responseURL)
```

Will provide this result:

```
https://www.facebook.com/
```

What if I want to use `http://` only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this using the `allow_redirects` argument when sending the request.

Like this:

```
import requests
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings() # to disable warnings

response = requests.get("http://facebook.com",allow_redirects=False, verify=False,timeout=5)
responseURL = response.url 
print(responseURL)
```

Hope this helps!